# Does EventWaitHandle have to deal with spurious wakes?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, waithandle

Note: I am constrained to .NET 3.5, so I can't use `ManualResetEventSlim`.

Do I have to deal with [Spurious wakeups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup) when doing something like this:

```
var waitHandle = new EventWaitHandle();
new Thread(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    waitHandler.Set();
});
waitHandle.WaitOne();
```

If so, are the correct memory barrier set when calling `Set` and/or `WaitOne` such that this would be safe:

```
var reallyDone = false;
var waitHandle = new EventWaitHandle();
new Thread(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    reallyDone = true;
    waitHandler.Set();
});
while (!reallyDone)
    waitHandle.WaitOne();
```

In particular, is it possible that the main thread in this example might not see that `reallyDone` is set to true due to instruction reordering or caching?  Does `reallyDone` need to be volatile in this case or is that unnecessary?

Comment: There are no spurious wakeups. Almost all Windows programs would break if there was such a thing. You are fighting windmills. But yes, the synchronization functions perform a full memory barrier (which is well understood but nowhere documented).

Comment: I don't agree: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx "Condition variables are subject to spurious wakeups (those not associated with an explicit wake) and stolen wakeups (another thread manages to run before the woken thread). Therefore, you should recheck a predicate (typically in a while loop) after a sleep operation returns."

Also in .NET 4.0+ there is code like this: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/ManualResetEventSlim.cs,635 "// Loop to cope with spurious wakeups from other waits being canceled"

Comment: An event is not a condition variable. This does not apply. The source code tells you that the framework handles this case for you. Spurious wakeups are not exposed to user code. They are an implementation detail that you dug up there.

Comment: @usr In .NET 4.0 the `ManualResetEventSlim` specifically has code to handle spurious wakeups. The `ManualResetEvent` class does not, which is what the OP is forced to use in .NET 3.5. This implies that `ManualResetEvent` is subject to spurious wakeups.

Comment: The source code in the link provided is for .NET 4.5.  `ManualResetEventSlim` is not available in .NET 3.5 so I am stuck using `ManualResetEvent`.  From what I could find, there is no documentation indicating that spurious wakeups are not a concern in `ManualResetEvent`.  I am reasonably confident that `ManualResetEvent` is backed by a Win32 condition variable which (per link above) does have to deal with spurious wakeup.  If you have a link to a reference (or source code) that proves that I don't have to worry about them then I would gladly accept that as an answer. :)

Comment: @ean5533 this is not at all implied. The implementation is completely different. All it does is delegate to the kernel. The docs say that there are no spurious wakeups so there aren't any.

Comment: @usr Can you link to the docs that say there aren't any spurious wakeups? I think that would sufficiently answer OPs question.

Comment: @MicahZoltu MRE is backed by a kernel event object (CreateEvent). The docs say "Wait waits until the event is signaled". That is unambiguous. The event is signaled when the function returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no spurious wakeups for events (MRE, ARE, and the slim versions). Almost all Windows programs would break if there was such a thing with those objects. You are fighting windmills. But yes, many of the synchronization functions including waiting and setting events perform a full memory barrier (which is well understood but nowhere documented). Condition variables to allow spurious wakeups (as the docs state). They are unrelated to events.

Also, why would there be spurious wakeups? Doesn't make sense from an API standpoint. The event could just loop internally and hide the spurious wakeups from you (indeed, MRESlim does that). I can only repeat: Almost all programs would break. That is not reality.

[The docs say:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Blocks the current thread until the current WaitHandle receives a signal.
>   The caller of this method blocks indefinitely until the current instance receives a signal.

These statements would be false if spurious wakeups were to exist in the context of events.

You are misinterpreting what you saw. You have a bug but it is not caused by the event. The `reallyDone` technique is not required.

Comment: Digging into the reference source it does appear that `WaitHandle` is not backed by condition variables as you mentioned in the comment above.  Instead, they are backed by Event Objects, which as you mentioned, don't have spurious wakeups.  More information on Event Objects can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686915(v=vs.85).aspx